# Puppet - controlling installed package version

Tags: rubygems, puppet

I have the following:

```
class compass {
    package { 'ruby-dev':
        ensure => installed,
    }
    package { ["rubygems"]:
        ensure => 'installed'
    }

    package { ['sass']:
        ensure => '3.2.0.alpha.277',
        provider => 'gem',
        require => Package['rubygems']
    }~>
    package { ['compass']:
        ensure => '0.12.2',
        provider => 'gem',
        require => Package['rubygems']
    }
}
```

When I do `gem list` after it has run, two versions of `sass` has been installed:

```
# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chunky_png (1.2.8)
compass (0.12.2)
ffi (1.9.0)
fssm (0.2.10)
listen (1.1.6)
rake (10.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.0)
rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
sass (3.3.0.alpha.212, 3.2.0.alpha.277)
zurb-foundation (3.0.6)
```

In order for my code to run, only `3.2.0.alpha.277` should be installed. It seems that the requirement from the `sass` package is fulfilled, but that the `compass` package requires sass "~> 3.1".

How do I make sure that only the `3.2.0.alpha.277` version of sass is installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly I ran this on a pretty much clean slate of Ubuntu 12.04 and it only installed the 277 version.

Also I don't think that the package resource can do this for you. You could handle it in an exec though, like:

```
exec { 'remove-sass-3.3.0.alpha.212':
  command => 'gem uninstall sass -v=3.3.0.alpha.212',
  unless  => 'test `gem list --local | grep -q 3.3.0.alpha.212; echo $?` -ne 0',
  path    => ['/usr/bin', '/bin'],
}
```

You could even wrap it up as a defined type:

```
define remove-gem ($version) {
  exec { "remove-gem-${name}-version-${version}":
    command => "gem uninstall ${name} -v=${version}",
    unless  => "test `gem list --local | grep -q \"${name}.*${version}\"; echo $?` -ne 0",
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/bin'],
  }
}


remove-gem {'sass':
  version => '3.3.0.alpha.212',
}
```

that way you can reuse it to remove other particular gem versions.